# Lubuntu 18.04.2 - reset audio driver?

Tags: sound, hdmi

I have multiple displays hooked up to multiple GPUs and one of the connections is via HDMI to a switch that is connected to an HDTV, so audio throughput (via HDMI) is required. I accomplished this with paprefs and the creation of a virtual audio device that combines both 3.5mm analog and digital sound so that both the speakers and HDTV have audio. The problem is that the switch (used because I need to connect more HDMI devices to the HDTV than it has HDMI ports) sometimes disconnects and this sometimes causes the TV to lose the audio, though not the video. A reboot fixes this, but I was wondering if there was a way to "reset" (meaning reload, while KEEPING the sound settings) the audio driver without having to wait for the whole PC to reboot.